# Removing div wrapper of textfield element in webform

Tags: webforms

I would like to remove div element on webform textfield.
Instead of :

```
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-vous-etes--nom">
  <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-vous-etes-nom" name="submitted[vous_etes][nom]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
</div>
```

I would like to have this :

```
<input type="text" id="edit-submitted-vous-etes-nom" name="submitted[vous_etes][nom]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this by overriding [theme_form_element()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) in your theme, eg, something along the lines of:

```
function YOURTHEME_form_element($variables) {

  $element=&$variables['element'];

  if ( /* this is a webform textfield */ ) {

    // create the html without the div wrapper

  } else {

    // do it the standard way

  }

  return /* the html */;

}
```

A look into `includes/form.inc` will show you the full `theme_form_element()` code that you could copy into your function above where necessary.

Comment: Can we custumise the output of the form tag ? : <form id="contact_form" action="" ..."

Comment: most definitely, see `theme_form()` in `includes/form.inc` and override it similarly as `YOURTHEME_form()` in your theme's `template.php` file

Comment: If you're trying to target only one element and have all others flow as normal, return your html for the element you want and have all others hit `return theme_form_element($variables);`

Comment: I try this but when there is `textarea` field it  yet return it with `div` wrapper

Answer (score 1):

```
function YOURTHEME_form_element($variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  if ( isset($element['#remove-div-wrap']) && $element['#remove-div-wrap'] === true ) {
    return preg_replace('/<div[^>]*>|<\/div>/is', '', theme_form_element($variables));
  } else {
    return theme_form_element($variables);
  }
}
```

Use hook_form_alter() to specify the affected fields:

```
function YOURTHEME_form_FORMID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['mail']['#remove-div-wrap'] = true;
}
```