# Form API multiple select drop downs in a paragraph

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to recreate the following paragraph in a custom Drupal form.

> [image]

How do you create multiple selects in a single paragraph?

Comment: What about wrapping them in a field prefix/suffix div... could that maybe help?

Comment: @longboardnode: That's an excellent suggestion and I will investigate it BUT some of the sentences can and do have more than one dropdown list item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a combination of wrapping the whole form in a div, so:

```
form['#prefix]='<div class="form-wrapper">';
  $form['markup1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'Hello this is a pulldown '
  );
  $form['pulldown1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array('option1', 'option2', 'option3'),
  );
  $form['markup2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => ' and this is another pulldown '
  );
  $form['pulldown2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => array('option4', 'option5', 'option6')
  );
form['#suffix]='</div>';
```

then use theme_form_element to remove the field wrapper divs that Drupal injects automatically around each field, see this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109305/removing-div-wrapper-of-textfield-element-in-webform). Once these individual divs around each pulldown are removed then the pulldowns will render inline with the markup.